# Search any twitter users feed

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

Its been a while since i last used the twitter api, Using Javscript, I would like to be able to search any random twitter users feed.

On the page I would enter there Twitter username and the app would go and find the users data returned as JSON.

I'm not after the code, I would just like to know what is the best API to use for this?

Do I just need the REST API, I assume this:

```
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search
```

Also, authentication do I need to authenticate my app? how should I do that if its needed?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all of my tweets (@edent) you will need to use the [User Timeline API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline)

For example:

`https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline?screen_name=edent`

Yes, you will need your app to be authenticated. You will need to use [OAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth)